# Get data from the API when language changed Ngx-Translate

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I have an Angular 12 web app which has 3 languages. I used Ngx-Translate to manage languages. Every things is ok but I have a small issue, I use `onLangChange` event emitter to subscribe to the current language which selected by user. I reload data from the API when language changed but my problem is when I navigate to another route and change language, the previous endpoints called again, it seems my components doesn't destroy or it's because the translate service leakage. Anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the main cause.
I was subscribed to the translate service onChange event emitter, which was alive even after component destroy, I solved the issue by calling  `.unsubscribe()` method inside `ngOnDestroy()` , so my observable closed after component destroyed and issue is fixed.